# SQL - calculate percentage increase in values of a numeric column

Tags: sql, sqlite

I want to calculate some trends based on the values I get in my SQL database. Particularly I am interested in getting the % increase of the values in one column (the value should be negative in case the values have decreased)

Can someone please advice how I should do this?

I cannot use stored procedures.

Thanks.

**My table has the following columns**

Date (numeric), Month (numeric), Orders (numeric), Price (real)

I want to calculate the % of change in the number of orders received from one month to next. I also want the direction to be a consideration i.e. the value returned should be -ve in case the sales have decreased.

Comment: "Can someone please advice how I should do this?" Not without some basic information on your schema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if sqllite allows for variables, but this is the way I do it in MySQL. I've just tested this and worked like a charm: printed 100% for a 10 to 20 increase, -13.04% for 46 to  40 decrease.

Hopefully it's similar in sqllite:

```
SELECT
  CONCAT(
    FORMAT(
      IF(@prev AND SUM(orders) <> @prev,
          -1 * 100 * (1 - SUM(orders) / @prev),
          0
        )
      , 2)
  , '%') AS variation,
    @prev := SUM(orders) AS orders
FROM
    (SELECT @prev := NULL) init,
    product
GROUP BY
  id_product
ORDER BY
  month
```

Of course, you'll need to tweak output as you need. This currently formats the precentages to 2 decimals and appends a "%" at the end.

Answer (score 1):

In order to calculate trends, you will need to store historical data of the values you are interested in.

Answer (score 1):

Should be useful if you have a integer column with the year+month (YYYYMM)

```
cast(
     cast(year(date) as nvarchar) + 
     replicate('0',2-len(cast(month(date) as nvarchar))) +
     cast(month(date) as nvarchar)
as int)
```

Then you only have to group, get the previous value and calculate.

```
select yearmonth, 
       sum(t.orders), 
       (sum(t.orders)/(select top 1 sum(orders) 
                       from table 
                       where yearmonth<t.yearmonth 
                       group by yearmonth 
                       order by yearmonth desc)-1)*100. as pct 
from table t 
group by yearmonth
```

*T-SQL syntax, hope that you can use it in sqlite*

PS: A division by zero check must be done to avoid further problems.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the column Date, but if there is only 1 row per month, the answer could be (I don't have sqlite, but I think this answer is ANSI sql):

```
select t.date
,      t.month
,      t.orders
,      case when t2.orders = 0 then
          99999.0
       else
          100.0 * (t.orders - t2.orders) / t2.orders
       end  "increase"
from   t
left join t t2 on t2.month = t.month - 1
order by t.month
```