# SQLite - calculate percentage increase in values of a numeric column

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-order-by, window-functions

I am interested in getting the % increase or decrease of the values in one column with respect to the previous value.

Can someone please advice how I should do this?

Thanks

This is what my table looks like

```
week |  sales  |

22   |  11     |
21   |  63     |
20   |  78     |
19   |  170    |
18   |  130    |
```

And this is what I would like

```
week |  sales  | growth

22   |  11     | -82.5
21   |  63     | -19.2
20   |  78     | -54.12
19   |  170    | 30.8
18   |  130    | NULL
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL - calculate percentage increase in values of a numeric column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653337/sql-calculate-percentage-increase-in-values-of-a-numeric-column) and [Calculate percentage increase/decrease from previous row value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30484373/62576) and several others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `LAG()` window function to get the previous value of `sales` for each week:

```
SELECT *,
       ROUND(100.0 * (1.0 * sales / LAG(sales) OVER (ORDER BY week) - 1), 1) growth
FROM tablename
ORDER BY week DESC;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=e59c69e64bd0c2eda803468d426284b3).

Comment: Thank you so much. I had a very similar query but the 1.0 did the trick since I wasn't casting integers into floats.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the diff between 2 numbers by percentage. You can try this formula.
Ex.

```
(@newSales - @oldSales) / ((@newSales + @oldSales) / 2) * 100
```

In your case:

```
SELECT (@sales - @week) / ((@sales + @week) / 2) * 100 AS growth
```

Comment: Thank you. Sorry if my answer wasn't clear. Basically it is the percentual change in sales from week 21 to week 22  and what I'm looking for is to get this percentual change for every week.